# Cannot Search AD from CSV using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to search AD account properties pulling from a CSV. The Import-CSV line works by itself. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is asking for a filter. I took this from another script I found where they said it worked. Others were using a For-Each statement.

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXX> Import-CSV .\listofnames.csv | Get-ADUser $_.DisplayName -properties displayname
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or an element of the argument
collection contains a null value.
At line:1 char:43
+ Import-CSV .\listofnames.csv | Get-ADUser $_.DisplayName -properties  ...
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: `$_` does not exist alone in a standard pipe. `$_` is the current pipeline object being processed within a scriptblock. You need to pipe into `foreach-object` to get that ability. `Import-CSV .\listofnames.csv | foreach-object { Get-ADUser $_.displayname ....}`

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks. I was playing around with it and got it when doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Its prompting you for the 'Identity' because that is how it identifies what user you are searching for.

Try this:

```
$users = get-content C:\Temp\test.csv

foreach ($user in $users){Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties displayname}
```

The CSV file just has the user IDs for the users who you would like to find info for.

Or if you can try the following:

```
Import-Csv C:\Temp\users.csv | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -identity $_.Name -Properties displayname }
```